# How to display data from another tab based on heading?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm in a problem as per the question, i want to display the data on the basis of heading. Heading's position may subject to change from column A to C per week, so =InputA1 formula is not what i need.It have to match both tab headings and display under output tab ( under the matching heading ).

One more thing i need is input may contain huge data where i want to

avoid the row if stock less than 10
avoid the row if code is empty
avoid the row if UNC is 0 or blank

A sample sheet is dropped below where there is estimated output also. Please help me.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14W6mLw4Z-1DN4TwHxbwx8KRcNfRg9u_B6m1dA0JjtSQ/edit#gid=692673040

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout the solution added to your [output tab](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14W6mLw4Z-1DN4TwHxbwx8KRcNfRg9u_B6m1dA0JjtSQ/edit#gid=692673040).

`=QUERY(BYCOL(A1:F1,LAMBDA(afx,FILTER(input!A:F,COLUMN(input!A1:F1)=XMATCH(afx,input!A1:1)))),"Select * Where "&"Col"&XMATCH("STOCK",A1:F1)&">=10 AND "&"Col"&XMATCH("CODE",A1:F1)&"!='' AND "&"Col"&XMATCH("UNC",A1:F1)&"!=0 AND "&"Col"&XMATCH("UNC",A1:F1)&" IS NOT NULL",0)`

-

[image]