# How can i select columns by name in a google sheet QUERY?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

I am trying to QUERY specific columns from a google sheet. I can do it using the columns as a number, however, if a new column is added, the number of the column changes.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FU4V.png)

For example: it is working with this function: =QUERY("name of the sheet!A1:BH1770", "SELECT Col1, Col3 where Col1 contains '"&$F2&"'", 0)

When i try something like this function, it is not working:
=QUERY(ImportRange!A1:BH1900,"SELECT "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0),4),1,"")& "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("RANK(",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0),4),1,"")&",
WHERE "&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0),4),1,"") contains'"&$F5&"'", 0))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74850386/5479575 Here's a similar Q&A you can have a look at...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by referring by wrapping the range in curly brackets and referring by column number with MATCH:

```
=QUERY({ImportRange!A1:BH1900},"SELECT Col"&MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Rank",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&" WHERE Col"&MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&" contains '"&$F5&"'", 0)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! I have been searching for this for an entire week. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! You can use an approach like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75160339/using-query-to-select-column-based-on-the-headers/75160744#75160744) when you need more columns and conditions; setting the headers with the help of TEXTJOIN and MATCH the whole array of headers to look for.

Comment: Hi Martin, just in case that you know how to solve it, there are some information that the QUERY does not bring, like for example: "2-X". Ive tried with =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT and it said that TO_TEXT has 4 arguments. I have tried to add parentheses with no success. Thanks again.

Comment: QUERY is pretty hard when working with different kind of data. If you don't need to do calculations with the data, you can try with:  
`=QUERY(INDEX(TO_TEXT(ImportRange!A1:BH1900)),"SELECT Col"&MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&", Col"&MATCH("Rank",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&" WHERE Col"&MATCH("Auditor",ImportRange!A1:BH1,0)&" contains '"&$F5&"'", 0)` - when handling different types of data it's very useful to use FILTERs. You can use one FILTER to select the columns, and other FILTER to apply to the conditions in each column